# How to group variable by quality number?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a madeup dataset that demonstrates the general idea of what I'm working with.

```
Quality <- sample(1:4, 300, replace = TRUE)
reader_ID <- rep(1:3, each = 100)

df <- data.frame(Quality, reader_ID)
df

quality_percentage <- ggplot(df, aes(x = reader_ID, y = Quality, fill = Quality)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")

quality_percentage
```

Here is the graph it produced. I'm trying to have each quality grouped together instead of having them all separate.

[image]

Comment: We were measuring growth in pictures of fish ear bones and assigning them a quality based on the clarity of the images. I am trying to show the percentage of each quality for each reader.

Comment: I think @akrun was making the point that you didn't include `Quality` in your made-up data set, so we can't run your example.

Comment: Apologies! I've included it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sort your data frame by `Quality` before plotting:

```r
ggplot(df[order(df$Quality),], 
       aes(x = reader_ID, y = Quality, fill = Quality)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I need an additional question for this, but do you know why the quality legend is a scale rather than 3 distinct values?

Comment: @dan_confused it's because numeric values are assumed to be continuous in ggplot. You can try changing fill to `fill = factor(Quality)`